# Why does this Kotlin / Retrofit script hang at the end

Tags: kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

This very simple Kotlin/Retrofit code doesn't exit normally. Why does it hang?

It's very simple, and adapted from the intro code at https://square.github.io/retrofit/

What is preventing the script from exiting on its own?

```kotlin
#!/usr/bin/env kotlin

@file:Repository("https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/")
@file:DependsOn("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0")
@file:DependsOn("com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0")

import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory
import retrofit2.http.GET
import retrofit2.http.Path
import java.lang.RuntimeException
import kotlin.system.exitProcess

data class Repo(
    val id: Int,
    val name: String
)

interface GitHubService {
    @GET("users/{user}/repos")
    fun listRepos(@Path("user") user: String?): Call<List<Repo>?>?
}

var retrofit: Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("https://api.github.com/")
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .build()

var service: GitHubService = retrofit.create(GitHubService::class.java) ?: throw RuntimeException()

val repoList = service.listRepos("octocat")?.execute()?.body() ?: throw RuntimeException()

println("The repos' names: ${repoList.joinToString(", ") { it.name }} ")

// The program just hangs unless I uncomment the next line
//exitProcess(0)
```

Comment: Probably non daemon threads keeping the process alive

Comment: What do you mean by saying "hang"? Do you get the expected output?

Comment: The program never exits. There is text outputted, but then nothing further happens